# Subset a list with xts objects that meet criteria using R

Tags: r, list, subset, xts

I have a fairly large List filled with xts objects that look like this:

`tail(LIST[[1]])`

```
          AMFD..Open AMFD..High AMFD..Low AMFD..Close AMFD..Volume AMFD..spcseccd
1984-12-21         NA      3.625     3.625       3.625         6400            978
1984-12-24         NA      3.500     3.500       3.500         4000            978
1984-12-26         NA      3.625     3.625       3.625         2200            978
1984-12-27         NA      3.500     3.500       3.500         6400            978
1984-12-28         NA      3.750     3.750       3.750         8700            978
1984-12-31         NA      3.750     3.750       3.750         4200            978
```

`tail(LIST[[2]])`

```
           ANTQ.Open ANTQ.High ANTQ.Low ANTQ.Close ANTQ.Volume ANTQ.spcseccd
1984-12-21        NA      3.25    2.750      3.000         800           976
1984-12-24        NA      3.25    2.875      3.063           0           976
1984-12-26        NA      3.25    2.750      3.000           0           976
1984-12-27        NA      3.25    2.750      3.000         100           976
1984-12-28        NA      3.25    2.750      3.000         700           976
1984-12-31        NA      3.25    2.750      3.000        1800           976
```

I would like to subset that list based on the last number of the 6th column: 
in example: `LIST[last(LIST[[x]][,6]) == 978]`

I thought something like this could work, but it also returns some Xts that do not meet the criteria:

```
SS <- sapply(as.list(1:10),function(x) {
  LIST[which(last(LIST[[x]][,6]) == 978)]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

after many trials, The solution I found is as follows:

`LIST[sapply(LIST,"[[",6) %in% 978]`

This will return all xts objects that have the matching criteria (978)